# Is there a way to define a type that's part of a merged declaration?

Tags: typescript

[The handbook uses this example to show declaration merging of interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeyDeBYAKGWQAsJgBzEsALmRAFcBbAI2gG5DiB3YAEzAk6jVh0IBfQqEixEKDNnxFkAZwRwANhGHM2UTgUkEtYZCyx0FyALy5S5KrWQBWADTJeAocgBs7tZrayACMAAzI4uxAA)):

```
// lib1.d.ts
interface Box {
  height: number;
  width: number;
}

// lib2.d.ts
interface Box {
  scale: number;
}

// my-code.ts
let box: Box = { height: 5, width: 6, scale: 10 };
```

Most of my code uses the this merged declaration, but I have one exceptional case where I need a type that is the first `Box` interface but not that second `Box` interface. It's worth pursuing because such a type would prevent me from introducing a kind of semantic runtime errors.

But this is only a simple example. In my real code, each "`Box`" interface has 30+ properties and both come from separate third-party libraries I don't have write access to. Both interfaces are defined in a declaration file wrapped in `declare global {}`.

If it were as simple as the above example, I know I could do something like this:

```
interface FirstBox {
  height: number;
  width: number;
}

// or

interface FirstBox extends Omit<Box, 'scale'> { }
```

But since my example isn't this simple, I would have to copy and paste the whole declaration file of one library, rename it "FirstBox," and synchronize any changes thereafter. I'd like to avoid that effort.

Is there a way to create a type out of a part of a merged interface?

Comment: I don't understand, both definitions come from third party libraries and they both merge into the same type automatically?  Like they use the same module name or something? Or do *you* merge them together somehow?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry I couldn't edit for a few minutes because of a site error. It's the former.

Comment: @jcalz They both define a top-level interface with the same name in a declaration file with no `import`/`export`. The merging is intentional and useful 99% percent of the time.

Comment: Then there's not much I can suggest. There's no way to tear apart merged interfaces. The only possibility is to get to them before they're merged.  You'll need to either locally fork those libraries or manually keep track of which properties come from where.

Comment: @jcalz aw. I can't say I'm surprised. I have seen some declaration files use imports to other types. I thought maybe I could refer to one of the library files' declarations with that somehow.

Comment: @jcalz `There's no way to tear apart merged interfaces.` To clarify, I don't need to "undo" the merge in a particular file. To me it would be good enough to define a new type that's the same shape as one `interface` without including the other. I think you already understood this when you replied, but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I understood. I mean, if they're merged, they're merged. There's no "seams" you can look at to figure out where things came from at the type level. Or at least I've never seen any. I've been looking through GitHub issues to see if there's even a feature request which would enable this functionality, but I haven't found even that yet.

Comment: @jcalz To be honest I wouldn't even request this as a feature. This is the first time it has come up for me and I don't know if it'll ever come up again.

Comment: So should I just post an answer saying essentially "no, sorry"? Or do you want to do that?

Comment: @jcalz go for it :) Thanks for the information